# Whats the equivalent of Eloquent's chunk in doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Laravel, you can use [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) to chunk results:

```
User::chunk(200, function($users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

What would be the equivalent in Doctrine2 (assuming a Symfony2 Entity repository)?

Answer (score 2):

### Memory optimization

If you just need to optimize your memory consumption you can use `iterate` method on Doctrine's Query object.

You can create iteratable result of the query. And process data as you wish one by one.

```
$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;
$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u');
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $row) {
    $user = $row[0];
    $user->increaseCredit();
    $user->calculateNewBonuses();
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush(); // Executes all updates.
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
    ++$i;
}
$em->flush();
```

In this case PHP doesn't load all objects at once and you don't need memory available for all objects. Just do what you need with your current entity in iteration process and detach it from entity manager. But you can meet some problems with memory outside of PHP. For example MySQL can query result and store it in memory. And if memory is not enough to store this data some processes can be killed. It all depends on your system setup. So if you encounter similar problems just set up your `my.cnf`.

See more here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

### Pagination

If you need to paginate over results you can use Pagination object from Doctrine:

```
$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

$c = count($paginator);
foreach ($paginator as $post) {
    echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
}
```

Or you can implement your custom logic with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your Repository-class.

See more here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/pagination.html

Comment: Thanks, I don't actually want to alter the data though, just query in chunks of 1000 rows or so. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359777/how-can-i-resolve-this-doctrine-memory-issue

Comment: If the table has a lot of rows, this still hits memory limits very quickly. Calling detach or clear does not seem to help.

Comment: It's not alternate chunks in laravel. The method iterate only return iterator with generator (yield), but no modify query for select with chunks.

Comment: @ZhukV, for most cases where you need chunks (as just for memory optimization) you can use `iterate`. In cases where you need pagination you can use https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/pagination.html. As topic starter said he needed memory optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain it has exact chunk functionality, but for processing large number of records you might wish to look at [batch processing in doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results).

Comment: Thanks I've looked at this. How would I adapt the last example there to do a query in batches of 1000?