# How can I resolve this doctrine memory issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The following code iterates over a table which has ~1,000,000 rows. I was advised to use Doctrine's iterateResult() method to avoid memory issues ([docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)) :

```
$batchSize = 1000;
    $i = 0;
    $q = $em->createQuery('SELECT i from MyBundle:Items i WHERE i.imgSize IS NULL');

    $results = array();

    $iterableResult = $q->iterate();
    while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {

        $results[]=$row[0];
        $em->detach($row[0]);

        if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {

            $em->clear(); // allegedly detaches all objects from Doctrine!
            $this->chunkedWhereCallback($results);

        }
        ++$i;
    }
```

The above code exceeds allowed memory even if I set the batch size to 1. If I alter the query to read `SELECT i.id, i.img FROM MyBundle:Items i WHERE i.imgSize IS NULL` then the memory errors are absent but then my $row array does not have a [0] key e.g:

```
array(1) {
  [5926] =>
  array(2) {
    'id' =>
    int(12794)
    'img' =>
    string(57) "http://some/url/1203/104962420.jpg"
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? Laravel's Eloquent handled this operation just fine but I wanted to port the code to Doctrine / Symfony2. I have tried setting the php memory limit to 1024M which should be more than enough and is more than I have available on the server.

```
Memory error is Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /Users/mre/Sites/ site/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 699
```

Comment: Maybe you set somewhere eager loading for all Doctrine entities and this entity has recursive relations?

Comment: Or it can be some recursive operations with allocating memory in your `$this->chunkedWhereCallback($results);`. Provide us code for this method.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov there is no entity relationship defined. The memory error happens before any other code runs.

Comment: Your problem is `$results[]=$row[0];`. You keep references to _all_ of the iterated items in this array. Meaning that GarbageCollector cannot release them, because they belong to the array. Meanwhile operations like `detach()` or `clear()` would remove reference to the item from the `EntityManager`, however it is not `EM` which prevents items from being gc'ed, but `$results[]`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and I'm not totally sure it is a problem with Doctrine, it seems like a issue with PHP itself.

Anyway the solution I found was to force PHP's garbage collection to occur like so:

```
$batchSize = 1000;
$i = 0;
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT i from MyBundle:Items i WHERE i.imgSize IS NULL');

$results = array();

$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {

    $results[]=$row[0];
    $em->detach($row[0]);

    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {

        $em->clear(); // allegedly detaches all objects from Doctrine!
        // Force PHP's GC
        gc_collect_cycles();
        $this->chunkedWhereCallback($results);

    }
    ++$i;
}
```

The call to `gc_collect_cycles` should free the memory and prevent exhaustion of the available memory.

Comment: Thanks. I did actually try this and think you may also need to call gc_enable() for it to work. Anyway, it didn't seem to help.  I've had memory problems with doctrine before - its not really very good at processing large amounts of data. What solved the problem to me was to use partial objects http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html thanks to a guy on IRC.